# Jest --changedSince tests ignored path patterns

Tags: jestjs

When I use `--changedSince=master`, jest runs all my changed files including config-files and files ignored according to `testPathIgnorePatterns` in the Jest config-file.

If I only have a small change plus a change in a config-file, `jest --coverage --changedSince` pre-hook fails because of that.

Is there a way to tell Jest to only test changed files and respect ignored patterns and config-files?